# '/tmp/hadoop-Aditya' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, command, external, tmp

I am getting an error when executing a simple Spark job via eclipse. Can someone please help? This is my code:

```scala
val sc=SparkSession.builder()
  .master("yarn")
  .appName("hive Test")
  .config("spark.hadoop.fs.defaultFS","hdfs://localhost:9000")
  .config("spark.yarn.jars","hdfs://localhost:9000/sparkjars/*.jar")
  .getOrCreate()
println("Testing")
```

Erorr:

> '/tmp/hadoop-Aditya' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Comment: my code val sc=SparkSession.builder().master("yarn").appName("hive Test")
      .config("spark.hadoop.fs.defaultFS","hdfs://localhost:9000")
      .config("spark.yarn.jars","hdfs://localhost:9000/sparkjars/*.jar")
      .getOrCreate()
      println("Testing")

Comment: Remove .config & execute code again ?